# does kernel's panic() function completely freezes every other process?

Tags: linux, kernel, panic

I would like to be confirmed that kernel's `panic()` function and the others like `kernel_halt()` and `machine_halt()`, once triggered, guarantee complete freezing of the machine.

So, are all the kernel and user processes frozen? Is `panic()` interruptible by the scheduler? The interrupt handlers could still be executed?

Use case: in case of serious error, I need to be sure that the hardware watchdog resets the machine. To this end, I need to make sure that *no other thread/process* is keeping the watchdog alive. I need to trigger a complete halt of the system. Currently, inside my kernel module, I simply call `panic()` to freeze everything.

Also, the user-space `halt` command is guaranteed to freeze the system?

Thanks.

edit: According to: http://linux.die.net/man/2/reboot, I think the best way is to use `reboot(LINUX_REBOOT_CMD_HALT)`: "Control is given to the ROM monitor, if there is one"

Comment: You could try it out in a virtual machine.

Comment: If modern day's Linux's `panic()` implementation is anything like the UNIX one, I think it actually depends on the machine and how the preemptive scheduler is scheduled. Considering that Linux is very well designed and usually has security as a top concern, I'm pretty sure that `panic()` stops the scheduler.

Answer (score 12):

Thank you for the comments above. After some research, I am ready to give myself a more complete answer, below:

At least for the x86 architecture, the `reboot(LINUX_REBOOT_CMD_HALT)` is the way to go. This, in turn, calls the syscall `reboot()` (see: http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v3.6.6/kernel/sys.c#L433). Then, for the `LINUX_REBOOT_CMD_HALT` flag (see: http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v3.6.6/kernel/sys.c#L480), the syscall calls `kernel_halt()` (defined here: http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v3.6.6/kernel/sys.c#L394). That function calls syscore_shutdown() to execute all the registered system core shutdown callbacks, displays the "System halted" message, then it dumps the kernel, AND, finally, it calls `machine_halt()`, that is a wrapper for `native_machine_halt()` (see: http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v3.6.6/arch/x86/kernel/reboot.c#L680). It is this function that stops the other CPUs (through `machine_shutdown()`), then calls `stop_this_cpu()` to disable the last remaining working processor. The first thing that this function does is to disable interrupts on the current processor, that is the scheduler is no more able to take control.

I am not sure why the syscall `reboot()` still calls `do_exit(0)`, after calling `kernel_halt()`. I interpret it like that: now, with all processors marked as disabled, the syscall `reboot()` calls `do_exit(0)` and ends itself. Even if the scheduler is awoken, there are no more enabled processors on which it could schedule some task, nor interrupt: the system is halted. I am not sure about this explanation, as the `stop_this_cpu()` seems to not return (it enters an infinite loop). Maybe is just a safeguard, for the case when the `stop_this_cpu()` fails (and returns): in this case, `do_exit()` will end cleanly the current task, then the `panic()` function is called.

As for the `panic()` code (defined here: http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v3.6.6/kernel/panic.c#L69), the function first disables the local interrupts, then it disables all the other processors, except the current one by calling `smp_send_stop()`. Finally, as the sole task executing on the current processor (which is the only processor still alive), with all local interrupts disabled (that is, the preemptible scheduler -- a timer interrupt, after all -- has no chance...), then the `panic()` function loops some time or it calls `emergency_restart()`, that is supposed to restart the processor.

If you have better insight, please contribute.