# Linux reboot() system call: why it calls do_exit(0) after kernel_halt()?

Tags: linux, kernel, system-calls, reboot, halt

This is related to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13413099/1284631

Now, the question is:

Why the reboot() system call, when called with `LINUX_REBOOT_CMD_HALT` parameter (see here: http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v3.6.6/kernel/sys.c#L480) is calling `do_exit(0)` after having already called `kernel_halt()`, as calling `kernel_halt()` boils down to calling `stop_this_cpu()` (see here: http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v3.6.6/arch/x86/kernel/process.c#L519), as part of `native_machine_halt()` (see here: http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v3.6.6/arch/x86/kernel/reboot.c#L680).

Or, it seems to me that `stop_this_cpu()` is never returning (it ends with an infinite loop).

So, it is `do_exit(0)` called just in case that `kernel_halt()` doesn't do its job and it return? Why not `panic()` directly instead, then?

Comment: panic make kernel stall, exit, probably reboot

Comment: @eicto: yes, I agree with that, I said the same thing in the ending phrase of my post. The true question is: why the call to do_exit(0) *before* the panic()? If you want to make the kernel stall, exit or reboot, why do not call panic() directly?

Answer (score 2):

Some ideas:

- It may be that `kernel_halt()` refuses to actually halt for a legitimate reason, though I can't think of any.
- `kernel_halt()` may be designed to also be called by a hypervisor or something at a higher or equivalent level than the kernel (custom SMI code maybe?)
- Perhaps the `kernel_halt()` function returns early, "scheduling" the halt, and the actual halt takes place some time later on some hardware.  I remember reading about performing an ATX power off in DOS in assembly - you would issue the `outb` instruction to intiate the power off, but you'd have to have some `nops`, an endless loop, or a `hlt` right afterward, as the actual power off could happen some cycles later.
- The calling process may wish to handle failure to reboot some other way than a kernel panic.